# Refused to load the script 'https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=__iframefcb566635'

Tags: javascript, html, content-security-policy

I'm trying to make a connection with the API "https://brasilapi.com.br/api/ibge/uf/v1", but I'm getting the following error:

```
chunk-OMODUTDX.js:79 Refused to load the script 'https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=__iframefcb559688' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

This is my HTML Head:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests" />
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d4c0dbaccd.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

This is my js code:

```
async function carregarEstados(){
    const APIResponse = await fetch(`https://brasilapi.com.br/api/ibge/uf/v1
    `)
    if(APIResponse.status === 200){
        const data = await APIResponse.json()
        console.log(data[1]['sigla'])
        for (let index = 1; index <= data.length; index++) {
            const doc = `
           <option value=${data[index]['sigla']}>${data[index]['sigla']}</option>
           `
           document.querySelector('#estado').append(doc)  
        }
    }else{
        console.log("Algo deu errado")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a Content Security Policy being set for your site, likely in a response header. You will need to identify where this CSP is set and modify it. It could be set in code, but more likely by default in your framework, on a web server or a proxy.